# javascript canvas document.getElementByClassName();

Tags: javascript, canvas

Im trying to export a canvas to a png but Im not sure if when calling for the canvas as a class i get the right return:

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('filemanager');
canvas.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
function download() {var dt = canvas.toDataURL();
this.href = dt; //this may not work in the future..}document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', download, false);
```

In the html i have: `<a id="download" download="YourFileName.jpg">Download as image</a>`
I read somewhere about how when calling functions you do not get back the same desired return, is the `document.getElementById()`different from `document.getElementsByClassName()` in terms of what you receive back?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array, so `var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('filemanager')[0]
;`

Comment: Another option would be `document.querySelector('.filemanager')`. See [Document#querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).